# Leaking CatalogEntry in com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.resolver.CatalogManager

Tags: memory-leaks

In one of my performance consulting assignment, I found that there was close to 1 million entries of com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.resolver.CatalogEntry dominated by com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.resolver.CatalogManager. More details below

There are web services deployed on JBoss Application Server. Then there is a Liferay Application  running on remote JVM that is consuming these services. The services are obtained through a Singleton class as follows

```
PaintingMasterEJBService paintingMasterEJBService = new PaintingMasterEJBService();
    public PaintingMasterService getPaintingMasterServicePort() {
        return paintingMasterEJBService.getPaintingMasterEJBServicePort();
    }
```

Each and every CatalogEntry in turn dominates two strings - 1) Containing the path to WSDL in the jar file for WebServices 2) The actual wsdl itself

All in all the the total of CatalogManager containing CatalogEntry eats up approx 640MB with just a few users logged on to the system. It is clear that CatalogEntry is leaking.

Questions I have are :

1. Is it that the way the Service is being obtained is wrong
2. Or Is this a known bug with the above mentioned classes

Will appreciate any solution / pointer.

Comment: There was an issue with jdk 1.6 update 34 XML parser. We changed over jdk 1.7 update 25 and everything worked great.

Comment: Is there any documentation about this issue related to Java or the related apache library?  I'm seeing a similar issue (though it only seems to affect some applications -- most work fine) but would like some documentation regarding it.